# What does DU stand for in term of a ladder level?

Tags: terminology

I was reading on some answers on quora discussing about an IT company, their reviews.
They mentioned CFO, CTO, CEO, COO, DU Leads.I think I've never heard the DU before. What does it stand for and in short what its role exactly?.

In case you need some more information. I'm curious about what DU stands for on this sentence:

> HR is always on DU Lead's side. I've never seen a decision of DUL been
>   challenged by the HR department.

Comment: Division Unit? Could be a lot of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge: DU stands for Delivery Unit.

The definition, well, varies widely. Usually, a DU is formed around a particular service / product delivery. It includes the technical as well as non-technical fields.